# Filtering on a list of paths affects the contents of the list variable

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher, collect

I am using neo4j Community Edition, version 3.4.0 on Windows.

I have a simple use case where I wish to collect a number of path results, combine these into a single list and then process the contents of that list. 
I wish to filter the common list for specific node attributes and process those nodes based on the category of the filter.
I then wish to apply further filters to the common list and process the resulting nodes in a similar way. 
Some nodes may be selected by more than one filter so it is important that one filter does not remove any nodes from the common list.

The problem I have is that, after the first filter, the contents of the common list is reduced to only those paths that include nodes that match that filter.
It appears the filter is affecting the contents of the list it is parsing and not just returning a new list of nodes that match the filter criteria.

The following queries are contrived but they demonstrate the issue I am facing:

Create the test data:

```
CREATE (b:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(c:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(d:D)
RETURN b, c, d;
```

The query:

```
// Establish two related paths
MATCH p1 = (:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(c)
MATCH p2 = (c)-[:FollowedBy]->()

// Join the two paths to create a single list
WITH collect(p1) + collect(p2) AS pList

// Unwind the common list so that it can be filtered for specific categories
UNWIND pList AS path 

// Filter for nodes in the 'D' category
WITH filter(n1 IN nodes(path) WHERE 'D' IN labels(n1)) AS dNodes, pList, path 

// Unwind the filtered set of 'D' nodes so that they can be processed
UNWIND dNodes AS dNode 
// ... do some dNode stuff

// Filter for nodes in the 'B' category
WITH filter(n2 IN nodes(path) WHERE 'B' IN labels(n2)) AS bNodes, pList, path 

// Unwind the filtered set of 'B' nodes so that they can be processed
UNWIND bNodes AS bNode 
// ... do some bNode stuff

RETURN path, pList;
```

If I run this query, 0 rows are returned.

What is actually happening is:

1) After collecting and joining the two paths, the common list "pList" looks as expected. It returns a single collection with two path elements.

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| pList                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| [(:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(:C), (:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(:D)] |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

2) After unwinding pList to path, pList now contains two identical records, one for each path value - Please could somebody explain why this is the case, i.e. why has the "unwind of pList into path" affected pList itself?:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pList                                                | path                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [(:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(:C), (:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(:D)] | (:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(:C) |
| [(:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(:C), (:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(:D)] | (:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(:D) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3) After filtering for nodes in the 'D' category and unwinding the resulting list "dNodes", the contents of pList are a single record and path now only contains the path corresponding to the filtered node?

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pList                                                | path                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [(:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(:C), (:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(:D)] | (:C)-[:FollowedBy]->(:D) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

4) After filtering for nodes in the 'B' category and unwinding the resulting list "bNodes", returning pList or path results in zero rows. This means it is not possible process the 'B' node?

I guess I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Cypher handles variables and filters and would appreciate it if somebody would explain the behavior I have described above.

Also, considering my requirement, how should I be doing this? I could perform multiple queries but it appears that my requirement is simple enough that I should be able to carry out the whole process in one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cybersam answered your question for #2.

As for #3 and #4, it's important to understand that UNWIND will provide a row per element of the list, and when done on an empty list it will wipe out the row (no elements, so no rows). This is what happened when you unwound the results of the filter, since one path didn't have :D nodes (and so that row was removed), and the remaining path didn't have :B nodes (and was removed).

We have an [entry describing this in the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-using-unwind-with-an-empty-list), along with a workaround in case you want to keep the row with a `null` result if the list is empty.

In your case, it would probably be better to use `FOREACH` to process the filtered nodes list (provided you're only using SET, CREATE, MERGE, REMOVE, or DELETE):

```
MATCH p1 = (:B)-[:FollowedBy]->(c)
MATCH p2 = (c)-[:FollowedBy]->()

WITH collect(p1) + collect(p2) AS pList

UNWIND pList AS path 

FOREACH(dNode in [n in nodes(path) WHERE n:D] | 
// ... do some dNode stuff
)

FOREACH(bNode in [n in nodes(path) WHERE n:B] | 
// ... do some bNode stuff
)

RETURN path, pList;
```

Otherwise, if you have more complicated things to do for dNode and bNode processing, you can use the trick in the linked documentation to `UNWIND [null]` using `CASE` when the filtered list is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the explanantion. I had missed the fact that UNWIND was effectively changing the scope of the current working set to only those paths that matched the filter - almost as if I had included the filter condition in a WHERE clause for the original path query(s). This makes perfect sense to me now, even if I haven't described my self correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In step #2, `pList` has NOT changed (into 2 identical records).

At that step, you have only `pList` and `path` as variables. Neo4j would represent every possible variable value combination as a separate row of data, and process each row. Since there is a single `pList` value and 2 `path` values, that results in 2 rows of data, which is exactly what you displayed in the table in #2.

Also, you did not show your full Cypher code, so it is unknown why the overall query returned nothing. There is possibly an un-shown `MATCH` clause that is not matching, which would abort the remainder of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suspected that table #2 was the result of it displaying all combinations. I just wanted it cleared up and that is why I was being so specific. However, that is not the real question here. The real problem I have is the behaviour of the filters and the apparent effect they have on the contents of the list. This is the full Cypher code. I trimmed it down to  the minimum just so I could demonstrate the issue I am having. You can run the first query to create the data and the second query will exhibit the issue.